# Vendor Bundle failed to load

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I searched for hours to solve my problem, but now I just don't know what to check anymore..

I created a new project for composer: https://github.com/Gcob/esvit-ng-table-for-symfony

Everything is fine until it comes to the appKernel.php, I declarate my new freshly downloaded from composer bundle like this: `new Gcob\NgTableBundle\GcobNgTableBundle()`, but I got an error message:

```
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 23:

Attempted to load class "GcobNgTableBundle" from namespace "Gcob\NgTableBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I don't know exacly how the appKernel finds its bundles, but I know that the namespace is important and the filename too, so my file `GcobNgTableBundle.php` has the namespace `namespace Gcob\NgTableBundle;` and the class declaration is `class GcobNgTableBundle extends Bundle` as it should be.

Is there any place I should tell the kernel that the file `GcobNgTableBundle.php` exists for vendor bundles? If some one got any idea, please tell me, but don't forget that I tried a lot of stuff ( first time asking question o_O )

Comment: By the way, go check the repo on github if you want the source code or download it to test...

Comment: Your composer.json file has NgTableBundle duplicated.

Comment: It looks like the `composer.json` file is set up wrong. `"psr-4": { "Gcob\\NgTableBundle\\GcobNgTableBundle\\": "" }` would mean the  root namespace would be `Gcob\NgTableBundle\GcobNgTableBundle` but it's currently set as `Gcob\NgTableBundle`. Best bet would be to fork it, fix it (possibly submit a pull request or an issue, depending on your feeling) and use your fork until the issue is corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of wasted time, I understood :P The answer of mim was in the good direction! I learned [here](https://jtreminio.com/2012/10/composer-namespaces-in-5-minutes/) how composer namespaces works. The appKernel in Symfony only loads the composer file `"vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php"` to load FAKE namespaces xD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your composer and add an autoload part.
Without it, namespaces can fail. Check [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors) for details. 
It must be similar to this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Symfony\\Bundle\\EsvitNgTableBundle\\": "" }
},
```

Check [this one](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/composer.json) for example.

Comment: Sorry but not even close to what is being asked.

Comment: I wasn't sure what was the relationship between composer.json and the appKernel xD but I tried, and I've already read the documentation without success because it is only indications for best practices... anyway, it doesn't work even with the code you posted.. but thx to try!